# How to create pandas DataFrame from nested xml

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I am trying to create Pandas dataframe out of XML. The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
    <Info>
        <Msg>Shop items.</Msg>
    </Info>
    <shop shopNr="01">
        <ItemNr>1001</ItemNr>
        <ItemNr>1002</ItemNr>
        <ItemNr>1003</ItemNr>
        <ItemNr>1004</ItemNr>
                <ItemNr>1010</ItemNr>
    </shop>
    <shop shopNr="02">
        <ItemNr>1002</ItemNr>
        <ItemNr>1006</ItemNr>
        <ItemNr>1005</ItemNr>
    </shop>
    <shop shopNr="03">
        <ItemNr>1009</ItemNr>
        <ItemNr>1006</ItemNr>
        <ItemNr>1005</ItemNr>
        <ItemNr>1002</ItemNr>
    </shop>
</Products>
```

I have tried using XML Etree as the code below. I have two problems.

First, I can not get the values of ItemNr as children of the root. Instead of getting the value, ie. 1001, I get

```
<Element 'ItemNr' at 0x000001E2D6C41B38>.
```

The second problem is when I am creating a dataframe out of the lists. I end up having a list of lists in items. Although the result is empty now since I could not get the values above, I want to end up with a flattened list.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
data = 'example_shops.xml'
tree = ET.parse(data)
root = tree.getroot()

shops = []
items = []
for node in root.iter('shop'):
    shops.append(node.attrib.get('shopNr'))
    items.append(list(node))

d = {'shops': shops, 'items': items}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

The DataFrame produced.

```
 shops                 items
0    01  [[], [], [], [], []]
1    02          [[], [], []]
2    03      [[], [], [], []]
```

desired output is:

```
 shops                 items
0    01  [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1010]
1    02          [1002, 1006, 1005]
2    03      [1009, 1006, 1005, 1002]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to append the text values from the `ItemNr` elements which are under the `shop` element to the items list and not the xml Element python object which is what you were doing.

The following code was working for me:

```
items.append([item_nr_element.text for item_nr_element in node.getchildren()])
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is the expected output:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
data = 'example_shops.xml'
tree = ET.parse(data)
root = tree.getroot()
shops_items = []
all_shops_items = []
for ashop in root.iter('shop'):
    items = []
    shop_Nr = ashop.attrib.get('shopNr')
    for anitem in ashop.iter('ItemNr'):
        items.append(anitem.text)
    shops_items = [shop_Nr,items]
    all_shops_items.append(shops_items)
df = pd.DataFrame(all_shops_items,columns=['SHOP_NUMBER','ITEM_NUMBER'])        
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  SHOP_NUMBER                     ITEM_NUMBER
0          01  [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1010]
1          02              [1002, 1006, 1005]
2          03        [1009, 1006, 1005, 1002]
```

If you want shops with individual items :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
data = 'example_shops.xml'
tree = ET.parse(data)
root = tree.getroot()
shops_items = []
all_shops_items = []
for ashop in root.iter('shop'):
    shop_Nr = ashop.attrib.get('shopNr')
    for anitem in ashop.iter('ItemNr'):
        item_Nr = anitem.text
        shops_items = [shop_Nr,item_Nr]
        all_shops_items.append(shops_items)
df = pd.DataFrame(all_shops_items,columns=['SHOP_NUMBER','ITEM_NUMBER'])        
print(df)
```

output:

```
   SHOP_NUMBER ITEM_NUMBER
0           01        1001
1           01        1002
2           01        1003
3           01        1004
4           01        1010
5           02        1002
6           02        1006
7           02        1005
8           03        1009
9           03        1006
10          03        1005
11          03        1002
```

Comment: Yes the first option is exactly the output. The second option also might help me later. Thanks